# Parts of print sticking to FEP bottom of resin tray instead of print plate

Tags: resin, sainsmart-kumitsu-kl9

In a print composed of three rows of parts, the center row is sticking to the bottom of the resin tray instead of the the print plate. I have tried the print five times with similar results.

These pictures include the best and worst results:

[image: best case: most of print on plate]
[image: worst case: most of print on FEP sheet]

Any ideas as to cause? Should I clean the transparent sheet at the bottom of the resin tray in any special way?

I found a great video providing solutions, and I am trying them one by one, [UN-STUCK your 3D Prints, and keep prints from sticking. (REAL QUICK)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7zwD9Z-ktc).

I am narrowing it down to the resin, or the printer/resin combination. The printer is a Sain Smart Kumitsu KL9, the resin is the [Elegoo 3D Rapid Resin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081N88WHS), notably in Black

Comment: Please post your printer's settings in order to better understand what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried printing diagonally using supports to minimise the area on contact with the FEP?

Comment: Please: (1) [edit] your question and put additional info *there* and not in the comments (that is not what the comments are for); (2) If you have found a solution in the links that you added, please post it as an answer, and (3) Which image is the best and which image is the worst results? Is the image on the left the worst results - it is pretty hard to tell. To clarify, [edit] the question and add image descriptions.  Many thanks.

Comment: Left is a plate (best), right is the worst (FEP sheet). It is pretty clear when you think about it. And the additional info was in comments as the intent was making it part of the answer, not of the question.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, when I had the same issue happening it was because my first layers exposure time what too short.

I was experimenting with bottom exposure time (in order to reduce the elephant foot) and sometimes, with very low exposure's time, I had failed prints that didn't even adhere to the print plate and remained stuck to the FEP (exactly as it happened to you).

Try increasing the bottom exposure time and check the exposure times your resin's manufacturer is providing.

Comment: Posting requests for information for the OP should be done in the comment section of the question. When you reach 50 reputation you'll be able to do yourself, I've put it in comments for you.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.